# So which should it be - 'lock and load' or 'load and lock'?

Tags: etymology

Employed in the Security Industry for over twenty years I have occasionally been encouraged to 'lock and load' - an exhortation to be ready for what is coming.

But I would have expected to 'load' myself with kit and courage - first - then to 'lock' my equipment and personal disposition as a secondary activity.

Indeed, my own experience of weaponry (confined to a firing range in Buckinghamshire) is of loading the weapon, then locking the weapon.

My observation, also, of larger pieces of belligerent equipment, is that they are loaded with ammunition, first, and then secured for firing.

---

The [Wictionary article](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lock_and_load) on 'lock and load' attributes the modern beginnings of its popular use to a John Wayne film in 1949. The script writer at the time is presumably quoting from an instructor manual, dated 1940, which refers to dummy (!) cartridges, reference 3. of the article.

It is doubtful that the filmed quote refers to 'musquets' (sic) and their peculiarities, reference 1. of the article.

---

But the article also references a British saying 'loaded and locked' :

> The transposition "loaded and locked" is used by Walter Scott in 1815, unambiguously in reference to a flintlock pistol.

And also a German saying :

> German "laden und sichern" ("load and secure")

---

So which is it  :

1) Do I 'lock and load' my 'musquet' and dummy catridges with the instructor and John Wayne ?

2) Or do I 'load and lock' with Walter Scott and the German army ?

3) Or do I forget practicality and just accept three words that sound vaguely like 'rock and roll' ?

Comment: Whether it makes sense or not, ["lock and load" is idiomatic](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lock+and+load%2C+load+and+lock&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Clock%20and%20load%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Block%20and%20load%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLock%20and%20load%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLock%20and%20Load%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLOCK%20AND%20LOAD%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cload%20and%20lock%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bload%20and%20lock%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLoad%20and%20lock%3B%2Cc0), for 40 years or so.  "Load and lock" was more popular in the WWII era.

Comment: _Load and (then) lock_ is the temporal order; but the fixed phrase is _locked and loaded_ (more often as conjoined perfecti participles than infinitives). So which do you want to refer to? The fixed phrase or the temporal order?

Comment: @JohnLawler Well, it seems I have a choice of the 'fixed' phrase. And my question was - which should it be, bearing in mind the practicalities involved ?

Comment: I'm beginning to think that 'lock and load' has more to do with sounding like 'rock and roll' than it has to do with anything practical.

Comment: [Benor & Levy (2006)](http://idiom.ucsd.edu/~rlevy/papers/benor-levy-2006.pdf) take a comprehensive look at relative factors (semantic/phonological/phonetic) in dictating order preferences in binomials.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Springfield Armory's manual for the M1 Garand rifle](https://archive.org/stream/gunmanual_Springfield_M1Garand/Springfield%20M1Garand#page/n9/mode/2up) (as John Wayne used in "The Sands of Iwo Jima"):

> 3. Prepare the rifle for loading. Pull the operating rod handle to the rear until the bolt is securely **locked** open.
> 4. **Loading** a full clip. Grasp the rifle with your left hand just forward of and under the receiver. Place the butt of the rifle on or against something fairly solid such as your thigh, a table or the ground. Using your right hand place the clip on the top center of the cartridge with your hand extended down the right side of the rifle so that your hand is just forward of the operating rod handle. Push the clip down until it latches. The operating handle and bolt should stay to the rear as long as downward pressure is maintained on the top cartridge.

Answer (score 8):

The reason for the order of 'to lock and load' has been almost entirely forgotten in contemporary use. The phrase is a relic from the period when guns used loose gunpowder, popularized in its imperative form since sometime before 1940.

> **lock**, *n.*<sup>2</sup>
>   In a gun or firearm which uses loose gunpowder: a mechanism by means of which the charge is exploded. Now chiefly hist.
>
> [*OED*](http://oed.com/)

In the case of flintlocks, for example, the lock struck flint; in the case of percussion locks, which succeeded flintlocks, the lock struck a percussion cap (a development enabled by the discovery and use of mercury fulminate). Other examples include the matchlock (a slow, smoldering match ignited the charge), the wheel-lock, the firelock, etc.

Examples of historical use of 'to lock and load' pre-1940 are comparatively rare, but make clear that the essential meaning is "to prepare to fire". For example, this from the [1836 *Lord Roldan*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=njp.32101068166592;view=1up;seq=18):

> "O! it can be read by ordinary light," said Davie, snatching a pistol from his pocket, and cocking it at the same moment; "There is my commission, steel mounted, inlaid with gold, *locked and loaded*....

Similarly, this next, dated 1793 from the [1894 publication of the *Collections of the New Brunswick Historical Society*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=coo.31924012142471;view=1up;seq=153):

> ...that afterwards Carvell brought in two musquets and justice Hubbard asked him if the guns were well *locked and loaded*.

An [1883 publication of an 1867 patent in *Patents for Inventions*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.hl592r;view=1up;seq=190) makes the sense particularly clear:

> ...the gun is *locked and loaded* by the muzzle; the gun is then unlocked and a percussion cap put on the nipple of the apparatus; the gun is relocked and it is ready for firing.

Comment: By far the better answer.

Answer (score 5):

The *OED* has an entry for "Lock and load," and its earliest attested use is from 1940, but in an article in *The New York Times*.

> Lieut. Col. Joseph T. Hart, range officer, boomed through his microphone, **‘Lock and Load’.**

- **1940** - *N.Y. Times* 19 Nov. 12/3

The definition provided in the *OED* is broken into literal and figurative meanings:

> (a) to prepare a firearm for firing by pulling back and ‘locking’ the bolt and loading the ammunition (frequently in imperative, as an order);  (b) fig. to ready oneself for action or confrontation.

I don't personally know much about firearms, but doing some research seemed to confirm the question's assertion that "loading" ought to come *prior* to "locking."

From the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolt_action) on "Bolt action" firearms:

> As the handle is operated, the bolt is unlocked and pulled back opening the breech, the spent cartridge case is extracted and ejected, the firing pin within the bolt is cocked (either on opening or closing of the bolt depending on the gun design) and engages the sear, then upon the bolt being pushed back a new cartridge (if available) is loaded into the chamber, and finally the breech is closed tight by the bolt locking against the receiver.

Unless someone with more expertise in firearms can explain an alternative meaning of "locking" that would occur prior to the loading of the weapon, I would posit that the phrase caught on in popularity simply because it rolls well off the tongue, often spoken and sometimes even written as "Lock N' Load," which was also the name of [a 1990 film.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0183414/)

For what it's worth, searching newspapers.com found some earlier uses of the phrase ***locked and loaded*** that refer not to guns but to shipments or vehicles.  Notably, a car or truck would need to be loaded before it was locked as well.  In both cases, it appears that the writers or speakers are ignoring chronology in favor of style when they use the words "locked and loaded" or "lock and load."

Comment: Very interesting. It seems the practicalities are being ignored for the sake of dramatic emphasis. Well, I never thought the film industry could ever, ever be so superficial.

Comment: @NigelJ Haha yes, hard to believe, isn't it. I'm hoping someone who knows more about firearms can add an answer that addresses this in more detail.  [Hot Licks gave a great answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/409173/228732) to my ["pop a cap" question.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/409171/what-did-pop-a-cap-mean-other-than-shoot-someone-in-the-19th-century)

Comment: [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lock_and_load) gives a citation from 1793, and [sproe.com](http://www.sproe.com/l/lock-and-load.html) references that older weapons such as flintlocks must be "locked" into a safe position so that "loading" does not produce an unscheduled discharge.

Comment: The same order of activity is true with regard to drunks who wind up at the city jail: first they get loaded, and then they get locked (up).

Answer (score 1):

This video from the TV show "Lock n' Load" by R. Lee Ermey, [episode on pistols](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ek9MSEnEmOM), doesn't squarely answer the question, but it is consistent with the interpretation that "lock" refers to cocking the hammer back before loading the percussion cap into the gun.  So, I think it should be "lock and load", as in the title of Ermey's show.

Answer (score 0):

When I was on the high school rifle team the range master would command us
 "ready on the right ready on the left" Load, Lock! commence firing."
That is the way I always understood the phrase. Load your rifle, lock the bolt and fire on command.

Answer (score 0):

In the series "The Pacific" it's "load and lock" and I found it's accurate usage for WW2 era. It also is more descriptive and correct thinking pattern. Lock and load is IMHO pure Hollywood BS which may have been tainted armed forces too. Gladly for me I am from Finland and we do things as they are, so we have command: "load and secure". So our weapon is ready to shoot as soon as one removes the safety.

Comment: Before you pronounce it Hollywood BS read @JEL’s answer.

Comment: But doesn't "secure" refer to safing?

Comment: Yes indeed. We load the gun and put safe on so one doesn't shoot accdidentally.

Comment: I know the historical reasoning. But as it was In the series "The Pacific" i.e. "load and lock", I really don't believe "lock and load" is used anywhere where real weapons are used. If they do well, it's stupid.

Comment: Isn't there a race condition in your ordering?  Can't the safety be engaged prior to loading the weapon?  Otherwise there's a brief period when it's loaded but the safety is off?